# How to capture frequency of words after group by with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a tabular data with keys and values and the keys are not unique.
for example:

```
+-----+------+
| key | value|
--------------
| 1   |  the |
| 2   |   i  |
| 1   |   me |
| 1   |   me |
| 2   | book |
| 1   |table |
+-----+------+
```

Now assume this table is distributed across the different nodes in spark cluster.
How do I use pyspark to calculate frequencies of the words with respect to the different keys? for instance, in the above example I wish to output:

```
+-----+------+-------------+
| key | value| frequencies |
---------------------------+
| 1   |  the | 1/4         |
| 2   |   i  | 1/2         |
| 1   |   me | 2/4         |
| 2   | book | 1/2         |
| 1   |table | 1/4         |
+-----+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you can combine multi-level operations with DFs, but doing it in 2 steps and leaving concat to you, this works:

```
# Running in Databricks, not all stuff required
# You may want to do to upper or lowercase for better results.
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [("1", "the"), ("2", "I"), ("1", "me"),
        ("1", "me"), ("2", "book"), ("1", "table")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
someschema = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(c1=x[0], c2=x[1]))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(someschema)

df1 = df.groupBy("c1", "c2") \
        .count() 

df2 = df1.groupBy('c1') \
         .sum('count')

df3 = df1.join(df2,'c1')
df3.show()
```

returns:

```
+---+-----+-----+----------+
| c1|   c2|count|sum(count)|
+---+-----+-----+----------+
|  1|table|    1|         4|
|  1|  the|    1|         4|
|  1|   me|    2|         4|
|  2|    I|    1|         2|
|  2| book|    1|         2|
+---+-----+-----+----------+
```

You can reformat last 2 cols, but am curious if we can do all in 1 go. In normal SQL we would use inline views and combine I suspect.

This works across cluster standardly, what Spark is generally all about. The groupBy takes it all into account.

minor edit

As it is rather hot outside, I looked into this in a little more depth. This is a good overview: http://stevendavistechnotes.blogspot.com/2018/06/apache-spark-bi-level-aggregation.html. After reading this and experimenting I could not get it any more elegant, reducing to 5 rows of output all in 1 go appears not to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another viable option is with window functions.
First, define the number of occurrences per values-keys and for key. Then just add another column with the Fraction (you will have reduced fractions)

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from fractions import Fraction
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf (StringType())
def getFraction(frequency):
    return str(Fraction(frequency))

schema = StructType([StructField("key", IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField("value", StringType(), True)])

data = [(1, "the"), (2, "I"), (1, "me"),
        (1, "me"), (2, "book"), (1, "table")]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('myPython').getOrCreate()
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

(input_df.withColumn("key_occurrence",
            F.count(F.lit(1)).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("key"))))
.withColumn("value_occurrence", F.count(F.lit(1)).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("value"), F.col('key'))))
.withColumn("frequency", getFraction(F.col("value_occurrence"), F.col("key_occurrence"))).dropDuplicates().show())
```